# Unable to get page access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm unable to get the page access token for some reason I only recieve the page id...
this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP-ID',
            status     : true, 
            cookie     : true,
            xfbml      : true,
            oauth      : true,
        });
    };
    (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
    }(document));
</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email,user_checkins,manage_pages">Login with Facebook</div>

<div class="result">Start</div>
<div class="result_app_installed">Start</div>
<script>
// Get access token
$.get('https://graph.facebook.com/102561956524622?fields=access_token', function(data) {
  alert(data);
});

// Get data if user is application is installed on that page or not.
$.get("https://graph.facebook.com/102561956524622/tabs/255792581098802",
   function(data) {
     alert(data);
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I am trying to do is to get the page access token and then check if application in installed on that page..
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

> FB.api('/me/accounts',function(response) {alert(response);})

The Page token is returned in data as access_token

You will need manage_pages permission.

Answer (score 0):

https://graph.facebook.com/102561956524622?fields=access_token 
won't work. In order to get an access_token for any fan page You need to do the steps explained here:

[writing on the wall on behalf of my fanpage](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9000870/writing-on-the-wall-on-behalf-of-my-fanpage/9001539#9001539)

Instead of using $.get it's better to use Facebook JavaScript SDK:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

so for the second request it would be:

```
FB.api('/102561956524622/tabs/255792581098802',
function(response) {

  alert(response);

});
```

Bear in mind that in order to make this FB.api call You need to authorize the app first

Comment: still not working ... i'm getting different error: "Error validating application." "OAuthException" this is my code: http://pastebin.com/YPdeU0tM

Comment: I think You're mistaking code and accessToken, You cannot use code as an accessToken, please refer to this documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: also to get an access_token using Javascript You can use http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/ the method if connected returns among others an access_token, if You debug it You'll see exactly what it returns

Answer (score 0):

Actuelly its very easy

```
FB.api('/'+[PAGE_ID]+'?fields=id,likes,name,access_token', function(response) {
    console.log(response.access_token);
});
```

Dont forget to check if user is logged in.